# Eigenvectors of block diagonal matrix with circulant blocks

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A_i$ be an $n_i \times n_i$ circulant matrix with full rank.

Its eigenvalues and eigenvectors are well known ( 
$a_0+ a_1 \omega_i + \cdots+ a_{n_i-1} \omega_i^{n_i-1}$ and  the columns of the $n_i \times n_i$ DFT matrix respectively, where $\omega_i$ is an $n_i^{th}$ root of unity and $A_i=circulant(a_0,\ldots, a_{n_i})$.)

Let $$A=blockdiag(A_1,\ldots,A_v)$$ be $n\times n$ with $n=n_1+\cdots+n_v.$

Then the eigenvalues of $A$ will be the union of the eigenvalues of the individual matrices. What about the eigenvectors? Especially when eigenvalues of $A_i$ and $A_j$ overlap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Block diagonal matrices with circulant blocks are diagonalized by block diagonal matrices with DFT blocks.

So the eigenvectors are the eigenvectors of the blocks, filled out with zeros.

Comment: Zeroes in the other blocks but does that mean if  two blocks share an eigenvalue  then it has two distinct eigenvectors, or 3? So (0, u, 0) and (0,0,v) and (0,u,v) if A2 and A3 share lambda?

Comment: The distinct eigenvectors exist even when the blocks share an eigenvalue. Just in that case, any linear combination of the distinct eigenvectors is also an eigenvector.